# Modulo of a negative number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Why is

> $347 \bmod 6 = 5$

but

> $-347 \bmod 6 = 1$

What is the difference?

Comment: $5\equiv -1\mod 6$.

Comment: $347\equiv 5 \pmod 6\implies -347\equiv -5 \pmod 6$  But we also have  $-5\equiv 1 \pmod 6$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\equiv b\pmod n$, then $(-a)\equiv (-b)\pmod n$. Thus $-347 \equiv -5 \equiv 1\pmod 6$.

Comment: So why is the answer + 1 and not - 5?

Comment: @the_prole Both can be.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:-

The basic difference lies here-

$(a-b)\neq(-a-b)\text{ or}-(a+b)$

$(347-5)=342$ but $(-347-1)=-348$ both of which are divisible by $6$.

Comment: So why is the answer + 1 and not - 5?

Comment: @the_prole Which $-5$...please add a detailed question....

Comment: Here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784660/modulo-with-negative-numbers

Comment: @the_prole Check my answer...Hope it solves your problem!!