# Modulo with negative numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

When I input this in wolfram I get false

> -347 mod 6 = 5

When I input this I get true

> -347 mod 6 = 1

And yet I know

> $-5 \equiv 1$

And additionally

> $-6*57 - 5 = -347$

but

> $-6*57 - 1 \neq   -347$

So it's strange that Wolfram's answer is true for +1

Why does Wolfram answer it that way?

Comment: What's so strange? $6 \times -57 + (-5) = -347$ so $-347\equiv -5\equiv +1$.

Comment: Well, isn't this what you'd expect?  -5 = 1 so 6x-57 -5 =1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $a\equiv b\pmod c$ means $c|(a-b)$

$-347\equiv1\pmod6$ is true because $6$ divides $(-347-1)=-348$

But,$-347\equiv5\pmod 6$ is not true because $6$ does no divide $(-347-5)=-352$.

Comment: So if the dividend is negative, I add the remainder to the modulus?

Comment: @the_prole It depends on the sign of the divisor....

Answer (score 0):

$$-347=5\pmod6\iff -347-5=0\pmod 6\iff 6\,\mid\,-352$$

and we can easily check that in fact $\;6\,\nmid\,-352\;$.

Yet

$$-347=1\pmod6\iff -347-1=3-248=0\pmod 6\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;-348=(-58)\cdot6$$

What you say would be odd if we had $\;5=1\pmod6\;$ (in fact, it'd impossible), *but we don't*. We have $\;5=-1\pmod6\;$, and $\;1\neq-1\pmod6\;$

Answer (score 0):

$-347 \pmod 6$ cannot be congruent to both 5 and 1 because these two numbers differ by 4 (and not by 6).

You can always subtract or add multiples of 6 to either side of an equation and it will still hold. For example, since $-347 \pmod 6 = 1$, repeatedly adding 6 to -347 (i.e. -341, -335, -329, etc) will eventually hit 1.  Before reaching 1, it was equal to -5. The next number after 1 is 7.  So we will never the number 5 in such a sequence.